# changing point of view issue

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm facing an issue with changing point of view in scene kit unexpectedly.
while debugging I could see that the `self.sceneView.pointOfView` had the previous camera node and setting the new camera node did not affect anything on the screen. it happens unexpectedly even without `setCompletionBlock`. sometimes it happens after the first change of view and other times at a very later time. and afterward cannot be changed and i have to kill the and restart to get it work. any idea what am i doing wrong? the following code is triggered after receiving `NSNotification`

```
[SCNTransaction begin];
    [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:4];
    [SCNTransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    MenuEntery *menu = [notification object];
    switch (menu.menuEntryType)
    {
        case kMenuS:
        {
            self.sceneView.pointOfView = _cameraNodeForS;
            [SCNTransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
                [SCNTransaction begin];
                [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:2];
                [SCNTransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
                self.sceneView.pointOfView = _cameraNodeForS2;
                [SCNTransaction commit];
            }];
            break;
        }
        //and other cases will here in between
    }
[SCNTransaction commit];
```

edit: cameras

```
_cameraNodeForS                 = [SCNNode node];
_cameraNodeForS.camera          = [SCNCamera camera];
_cameraNodeForS.position        = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, S_DIST);
_cameraNodeForS.camera.xFov     = 50;
_cameraNodeForS.camera.zFar     = 2100000;
_cameraNodeForS.camera.aperture = 1/50;

_cameraNodeForSOrbit = [SCNNode node];
[_cameraNodeForSOrbit addChildNode:_cameraNodeForS];


_cameraNodeForS2                 = [SCNNode node];
_cameraNodeForS2.camera          = [SCNCamera camera];
_cameraNodeForS2.position        = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 10000);
_cameraNodeForS2.camera.xFov     = 50;
_cameraNodeForS2.camera.zFar     = 2100000;
_cameraNodeForS2.camera.aperture = 1/50;

_cameraNodeForS2Orbit = [SCNNode node];
[_cameraNodeForS2Orbit addChildNode:_cameraNodeForS2];
```

Comment: Hard to say from what's here. Best guess is that your notification isn't being delivered on the main thread, so you're talking to SceneKit from a background thread. Re-dispatch to the main queue before your transaction and see if that helps?

Comment: @rickster thanks for answering I' have found the problem it was caused by another [SCNTransaction begin] which didn't had commit. that was a very dumb mistake.

Comment: Great! It'll help others with similar problems if you give a bit more detail about that in an answer (and then accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem which was caused by me. First about the project. I have a `SCNView` which has `SKScene` with `UITableViewController`. The table contains a menu of different cells pointing to a node on the scene. every node has its own camera. if the user chooses a menu entry then the point of view changed to that object's camera with animation as stated in the question. beside animating camera-to-camera changes, I had to animate camera orbit while the user touching and dragging on the screen. so I have used `SCNTransaction` with begin but somehow disabled the line `[SCNTransaction commit];` mistakenly. a lesson re-learned, for every "begin" one need to "commit", otherwise unexpected behaviour will occur.(the solution reminded me of forgetting to commit sqlite insert or update).